# Audio not stop playing in a specific scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a C# script in Unity. I code audio playing in multiple scenes and it doesn't stop playing in another scene I expected.

[This is the scene I start playing the audio script **BgScript.cs**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU9BM.jpg)

This code is used for playing and stopping audio.

**BgScript.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BgScript : MonoBehaviour
{
private static BgScript instance = null;
    public static BgScript Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null && instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

[This is the image of where I place a script **AudioPause.cs** for audio stopping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhcWU.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhcWU.jpg)

And this is my audio stopping code

**AudioPause.cs**.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioPause : MonoBehaviour
{
    void start() {
        BgScript.Instance.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start() is lowercased in AudioPause.cs and thus the code never runs because it is never called.

```
void Start() { }
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html